# Line breaks are stripped by ckeditor after saving a node programmatically

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes

I'm setting a value to a long text using this code :

```
$node->language = $language->language; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
$node->field_job_description[$field_langcode][0]['value'] = $description;
$node->field_job_description[$field_langcode][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';
$node->field_job_description[$field_langcode][0]['save_value']  = $description;
```

When viewing the node the line breaks are showing, when I edit this node using ckeditor all link breaks are automatically removed

Comment: Are line breaks retained when saving node via UI?

Comment: When viewing the node before editing the line breaks are present but once you edit ckeditor removes every line break, if I save then removes them

Comment: Did the answer below help solve your problem?

Comment: No it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I would try disabling the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) in CKEditor as a starting point.

In a typical scenario, most people are exclusively using CKEditor to set and update their field values, so the content stays exactly the same between viewing and editing the node, which is the behavior you're expecting.

However, since you are setting the field programmatically, when you edit the node it's the first time CKEditor is seeing the field value (i.e. the first time CKEditor filters are being run). CKEditor will filter and "correct" your HTML to its standards, so it's not safe to assume your field value will be untouched if it's the first time CKEditor is seeing it.

Your options are to 1) tweak how CKEditor filters your HTML, or 2) conform the HTML you're programmatically saving to the CKEditor standards.

Comment: Any hints on how to tweak CKEditor? I've imported a bunch of WordPress content that contains line breaks instead of paragraph tags. Although I can easily filter this on the front end, if anything is edited on the back end (via CKEditor), all line breaks are lost and I'm left with a wall of text. Using latest -dev version of CKEditor module and CKEditor library v 4.4.3. Thanks!

Comment: @othermachines Does it strip the line breaks when you go to edit with CKEditor, or do they disappear after saving? If the latter, I would check your Drupal text formats. There's an option to convert line breaks to HTML that you could flip on/off.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As I said, it's filtered on the front end. If I never had to edit the nodes again it would all be swell. It's just when I open it up in CKEditor and save that the breaks are lost. I've rectified this in the meantime by running the Drupal Filter function _filter_autop() on the data in the database, but it would have been nice not to have to do that.

Comment: The reason I ask is because CKEditor has its own set of filters that will modify the HTML when it's instantiated on a <textarea> (i.e. when you load the node edit page), and your Drupal text formats can also modify that HTML again when the node is saved. So you have two sets of filters that can work together to create a confusing chain of behaviors. If you disable all the Drupal text format options and turn the CKEditor Advanced Content Filter off (try sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js if you use the Libraries module) then it should leave your node body completely untouched.

Comment: Thanks, but I did all of that with no joy. What I was wondering is if there was some CKEditor filter or plugin that I somehow missed that would convert the line breaks to paragraph tags and breaks when the content is loaded into the editor. What I was getting was a wall of text (no breaks or tags) even though the line breaks exist in the database. Of course once this was saved all formatting was lost in the db as well.

Comment: Hmm, give this module a shot: https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_linebreaks. Hopefully that does the trick for you!

Comment: I looked at that, but unfortunately it is not compatible with CKEditor module. :(

Comment: Bummer. CKEditor has a ton of filters and configuration options, so at this point the most I can recommend is looking at their [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR). You can fiddle with most of the values in `ckeditor.config.js`. Make sure to clear your browser cache when you update values there because it's really heavily cached and you won't see your changes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem from importing from a CVS. I was using wysiwyg module and wysiwyg linebreaks module mentioned above but needed to switch to ckeditor for Media 2.0 module.

I found that you can patch ckeditor module include includes/ckeditor.utils.js

here is the thread on drupal.org with the patch
[D7] Linebreaks converter for CKEditor toggle mode
https://www.drupal.org/node/1084924

this works when opening the node edit form. you can't switch to plain text however as the break and paragraph tags added are retained.

Answer (score 0):

Under `admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html` add the breaks tag at the very bottom inside the **Allowed HTML tags** vertical tab.